# How do I split a 60-amp subpanel into 3 20-amp circuits?

Tags: electrical

I'm putting a 60 amp service from my main breaker to a sub-panel.

How would I separate that to 3-20amp breakers?

And what size wire do I need to run?

It is underground and 100 feet from my house.

Comment: The sub-panel and breakers are what separates the circuits. Can you elaborate as to what you mean by this?

Comment: I need to run 3 different breakers one for pool one for hot tub and one for lights and outlets. I'm running a 60 amp service from my house to the sub-panel

Comment: Wow! If this is for a pool and hot tub I want to STRONGLY suggest having a professional electrician either do this job or oversee it for you. There are simply too many important codes and requirements to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

6 AWG copper wire (x4) for a run less than 75ft., 4 AWG copper wire (x4) for runs less than 150ft.

You can pull individual conductors through conduit, or use underground feeder cable (Type UF).  Individual conductors will have to be rated for wet locations, so you'd likely use THWN.

Since it's a secondary panel, you'll need to run a grounding conductor.  If you're pulling conductors through conduit, you'll want a white grounded (neutral), green or bare grounding, and two colored ungrounded (hot) conductors (black and red are common for hot conductors).

You'll use individual branch circuit breakers in the panel, to divide into smaller (15-20 ampere) branch circuits.

You'll also have to isolate the neutral bar in the panel, so that it's not bonded to ground. Which likely means removing a jumper between the grounding and neutral bars.